# Relate two tables with different number of entities

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, attribute-joins, relates, one-to-many

I want to join two layers: One which has information about the height and width of the wind turbines (fields to join) with only 4 or 5 entities or sometimes less, and the other is a layer with lots of entities but there is not really a field which I could relate the first layer with.
So I would like to know how can I join both layers? I gue
I thought about simply add a join as the main goal is just to add the fields of one attribute table to another.
[image]

[image]
Furthermore, if the values can be updated automatically to the target layer every time that the values change in the origin layer that would be nice.

Comment: If you don't have a commun field that won't be possible (if both layer are geographic layer you may join by location but that will create a third layer unless you do it dynamically with a virtual layer...)

Comment: J.R thank you. I've just created an additional field since all the values are the same for the first table so I can  make the relationship